# Windows 2008 R2 Server on AWS - sudden RDP issue

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services

I manage a business with seven offices that all RDP to a Windows 2008 R2 Server on AWS. Most client machines are iMacs with the Microsoft RDP software. This solution has been faultless for 3 years and then suddenly out of the blue, some of the client machines started getting a 0x204 error when trying to connect. This error is not specific to any location, ISP (we have 3 different ISP's), machine or user. The fix is to either keep trying and it will eventually connect or wait a day and it will work again.

We have 20+ machines connecting and this problem only happens to a handful of machine at a time but not always the same machines or same location

In desperation I went and created a new AWS server but this has not solved the issue. There are no errors in the Server log.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
O

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: on the clients trying to connect. The iMacs.